# HTML heading unexpectedly calls for CSS class

Tags: css, html, class, formatting, frontend

I cannot figure out why this header

#### "RESEARCH AND DEVELOPMENT"

inherits of the class .consult h3, when the html file is actually void of that class.
If I change the font-family inside .consult h2, h3 the title change accordingly.

What are the case scenarios for this to happen?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma in a CSS selector separates entire selectors, so the CSS:

```
.consult h2, h3 {
```

is the same as

```
.consult h2 {
    ...
}
.h3 {
    ... same stuff ...
}
```

So the CSS is applied to every `h3` element.

Note that `.consult h2` selects all `h2` elements inside an element with class `consult`. There is no equivalent to parentheses in CSS, so to select all `h2` and `h3` elements inside an element with class `consult`, you must do:

```
.consult h2, .consult h3 {
```

If you meant to select all `h2` and `h3` that have class `consult`, you need:

```
h2.consult, h3.consult {
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something very basic! It was indeed the comma separation causing this. And thank you for elaborating on inheritance and formatting options! very much appreciated